# how to use jquery plugin silviomoreto?

Tags: jquery-plugins

i am trying to this plugin https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

It transforms your select into a bootstrap dropdown button. It keeps the select to keep the form consistency, so you can submit the selected value.
however, no transformation occurs.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Final_Year_Project_Allocation_System.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!-- styling select -->
    <link href="silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-d4ec9bd/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-d4ec9bd/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-d4ec9bd/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-d4ec9bd/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>:: Project Allocation System</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="span12"><br /><br /><br /></div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class=" span3">
                <!--Sidebar content-->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SideBarContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <!--Body content-->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent" runat="server">
**<select class="selectpicker">
    <optgroup label="Picnic">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Camping">
    <option>Tent</option>
    <option>Flashlight</option>
    <option>Toilet Paper</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>**

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put the code you've tried so far on jsfiddle ? It would help a lot to understand the problem, thks.

Comment: it display a normal select button.

Comment: It looks like you're including the script twice: first the non-minified (bootstrap-select.js) and then the minified version (bootstrap-select.min.js). Pick one, not both. And you don't initialize the script anywhere (`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`).

Comment: it does not work even if i include in once :(

Comment: Did you initialize the plugin?

Comment: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: thanks i already figured it out :)